# MPI_ALLREDUCE PROBLEM

Tags: mpi

I have a code which has a 2D local array (cval).This local array is being calculated by every processor and in the end I call MPI_ALLREDUCE to sum this local array to a global array(gns).
This local array has different sizes for different processors.The way I do a all reduce is as follows

```
k = n2spmax- n2spmin + 1 ! an arbitrary big value

do i = nmin, nmax
     call MPI_ALLREDUCE(cval(i,:),gns(i,:),k,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
end do
```

Is this the correct way of writing it.I am not sure about it ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it this way.  MPI_Allreduce requires that all of the processes in the communicator are contributing the same amount of data.   That's why there's a single count argument.

To give more guidance on what is the right way to do this, we'll need a bit more clarity on what you're trying to do.   Is the idea that you're calculating gns(i,j) = the sum over all ranks of cval(i,j), but not all ranks have all the cval(i,j)s?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.Let me explain this in detail.I have two global ranges say (nmin,nmax) and (n2min,n2max). Hence gns has to be calculated for the entire range i.e  gns(nmin:nmax,n2min:n2max).While these two ranges are divided among processors in an unequal fashion.So cval is the local array on each processor working on the the local ranges.At the end all the values of cval need to clubbed together in a single array gns.

Comment: @Vaibhaw: If you're summing the values, then you can pad smaller `cval` arrays with zeros so that they're all the same size, and your result will be the same.

Comment: Actually I have the cval allocated as cval(nmin:nmax,n2min:n2max) i.e same as gns.Before MPI_ALLREDUCE call, each processor  works on cval(nl:nh,nln2:nhn2) where [nl,nh] is the local range for [nmin:nmax] while [nln2,nhn2] is the local range for [n2min,n2max].[nln2,nhn2] is of different size for different processor.I give you an example:

Comment: 1st proc:[nl,nh],[nln2,nhn2]= [0,88],[0,88]

Comment: 2nd proc:[nl,nh],[nln2,nhn2]= [88,125],[0,125]

Comment: If all the cvals have the same actual size and the only difference is that they're mostly zeros, then yes, you can do the mpi_allreduce, and in fact you can do it in one line rather than looping: `mpi_allreduce(cval, gval, (nh-nl+1)*(n2max-n2min+1), MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)` unless the arrays are strided for some reason.  But if the regions of cval are disjoint -- if no two ranks are working on the same indicies of cval -- you don't need to do the allreduce; you can reduce your data transfers by using mpi_allgather instead.